# hbm files attributes use

Tags: hibernate

I am new to hibernate, and while writing one of .hbm files, few questions raised to my mind, and posting them on SO in hope to get a answer

Q:
we map property of pojo to db fields

```
<property name="birth_dt" type="date"> <column name="BIRTH_DATE" length="4" /> </property>
```

how does **type** attribute help/not-help inside the property tag and what is the dif between type as "date" and "java.util.Date"? 
how does **length** attribute help/not-help inside the column tag?

what i want to understand is: what is the use of these attributes

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Type: it is the type from the Hibernate type system. You may, for instance, use a custom type here. When mapping a basic value type, there is no difference between specifying the java type name or the Hibernate type, see the [reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-types-basictypes).

Length: it is used for schema generation for data types which support a length, like varchar.